# Python : Unable to find mistake in my program

Tags: python

For context, the program below is a program to calculate the user's chances in winning a specific bet, taking first his initial money, the cost/"roll", possible outcomes, . Here is my code:

```
from random import randint

def prompt_user():
    # ask the user to input custom values
    --snip--
   # here i prompt the user to input values that will be returned below 
    bank = startcash
    return bank, price, lowroll, highroll, outcomes, desired_outcomes, testnum

def lucky_or_not(bank, price, lowroll, highroll, outcomes, desired_outcomes, testnum):
    while bank >= price:
        for num in range(0, testnum):
            bank -= int(price)
            lucky = randint(1, outcomes)
            if lucky == desired_outcomes:
                bank += highroll
            else:
                bank += lowroll
    return bank

#Find whether the user has made profit or not.
def print_results(bank):
    print(f"your current money is {bank}.")

def main():
    vals1 = prompt_user()
    vals2 = lucky_or_not(*vals1)
    print_results(vals2)

main()
```

I know the title is a bit vague, but unfortunately I cannot identify my program's fault and I do not know what to ask specifically. What I know from running tests is that there is a logical error in my program's loop, where the output for the "bank" variable occasionally displays a negative integer. Sample faulty output:

```
insert your initial cash: 10000
insert the amount of money you spend in one roll: 2800
insert the highest amount of money you think ur gonna win: 5000
insert the lowest amount of money you think ur gonna win: 1000
insert the amount of outcomes possible: 6
insert the amount of desired outcomes: 1
Enter desired number of tests: 100
your current money is -90000.
```

I know this is an error, since I programmed the *while* loop to stop if the user does not have any money("bank") left to do a roll("price"), so an output that displays a final "bank" value("your current money") any lower than 2800(the "price" for a roll) should be impossible, much less a negative value. What can I do here?

Comment: Question could be better in Code-Review. But I'm not sure about the rules there.

Comment: Did you debug your code to see which part gives the error?

Comment: I did, it does not work since there is technically no error as I did not specify on whether the bank value must be above zero. My problem is that the while loop doesn't seem to do its job

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

Inside the for loop, after `bank -= int(price)`, check `if bank >= price`. If not, `break` the for loop.

#### Solution 2:

Check the `while` condition by `while bank >= price * testnum:`

Comment: am i right to assume that testnum is a new variable defined in the lucky_or_not function?